# Is changing container width in Bootstrap.css manually enough?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the container width of the Bootstrap when the screen width is more than 1200px which is currently set to 1170px, to 1275px.

I know that there is a [customizing tool](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/) from Bootstrap, but it does not support the version I currently have (3.3.7), its in the list but when I open it, it goes to 3.4 .

So does changing the Container width in Bootstrap.css manually to 1275px instead of 1170px (1140 + 15 + 15) is enough ? or I have to do something.

Comment: Yeah it will be enough but try in your custom css, don't edit the default bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is far enough. You can also create a custom container and use it with default container (just overwriting the width).

CSS :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.my-custom-container{
    width:600px;
}}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
.my-custom-container{
    width:720px;
}}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.my-custom-container{
    width:900px;
}}
```